# Swift: How can I parse a JSON response from a server if it's wrapped in an array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Swift n00b here.

I'm getting something like this as a response from a server:

```
[
  {
    "foo": [], 
    "bar":"asdf",
    ...
  }
]
```

Now I understand how to parse regular JSON, but not when it has an array as the base element.

Here is code I used so far, which would work for regular JSON:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in

    // check for any errors
    guard error == nil else {
    print("error calling POST on \(String(describing: urlRequest.url?.absoluteURL))")
       print(error!)
       return
    }

    // make sure we got the data
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }

    let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!

    // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
    do {
        guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
            as? [String: Any] else {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
        }

        ... // do whatever with the response

    } catch {
        print("an error occurred")
        return
    }
 }

task.resume()
```

The error I'm getting from that is "error trying to convert data to JSON.

The easiest way to parse that response I can think of is making a substring from 1 to length - 1 and then parsing it, but that doesn't seem particularly safe.

Is there any way I can parse that response into a `[Dictionary]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular JSON"? That is "regular JSON". The top level of a JSON structure can be either an array or a dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok I wasn't sure about that. By regular JSON I mean JSON with a dictionary at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is regular JSON. An array at the top level is just as valid (and regular) as a dictionary.

Simply update your cast accordingly:

```
guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
    as? [[String: Any]] else {
```

That indicates that you have an array of dictionary. Now you can iterate the array and get each dictionary as needed.